# C# combo box issue

Tags: c#, combobox, active-directory

I have a combo box of items that I fill with the OUs in a container.  What I want to do is 2 things.  One set the value of my OU variable to the item chosen from the OU list and 2 update a textbox field in the GUI to use this dropdown value.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
    private void oulist_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        oulist.SelectedValue = txtboxOU.Text;
        sou= oulist.SelectedValue;

     }
```

I can't get this to work with SelectedValueChanged or the SelectionChangeCommitted event.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

`SelectedValueChanged` is very probably the event you want to use here, but from your description of what you want to do, I'd expect to see:

```
txtboxOU.Text = oulist.SelectedValue;
```

rather than

```
oulist.SelectedValue = txtboxOU.Text;
```